# Mongoose query does not return values when comparing string digits

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For the last 9 hours I`m trying to fix one bug so I have code

```js
let query = User.find(); 
if(req.query.from){
    query = query.find({date: {$gte: req.query.from}});
}
if(req.query.to){
    query = query.find({date: {$lte: req.query.to}});
}
const User = await query;
res.status(200).json({status:'Success', User})
```

And the problem is when I do for example

```js
req.query.from = 1

req.query.to = 9
```

Everything works but when I do

```js
req.query.from = 1

req.query.to = 11
```

It doesn't return anything.

Single digit numbers can be query but If I want to mix single digit with multi digit then doesn't work.
Can anyone help me solve this problem

Edit:
My user Schema

```js
const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    date: {
        type:String
    },
    title: {
        type:String
    },
    description:{
        type:String
    },
    location:{
        type:String
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you possibly share some sample documents from the `users` collection that we can test the query with and perhaps the `User` schema definition as well?

Comment: @chridam  I just update

Comment: not sure if `$gte` and `$lte` works perfectly with `type:String`

Comment: change it to `Date type`

Comment: Please post a sample `date` field's value _and also_ `req.query.from` value. For correct comparison, the values and their format matter in the case of date field values.

Answer (score 1):

The [comparison query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt), [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gte), [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_lt) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_lte) do not generally work well with string digits as types in MongoDB are strict and do not auto-convert like they would do
in other systems. To compare against a number with [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt)/[`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gte) or [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_lt)/[`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_lte), the values in your document also need to be a number. Thus you have an option of changing
the schema design of the Date field to be an int or double.

For your case, since the date field is already of String type, you can utilise the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator to convert the field within the query as it works well with aggregate operators such as [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) or [`$toDouble`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/). You would also need to parse the parameter values to integer for correct comparison with the query.

You would thus in the end require a query like this should you decide to stick with the existing schema:

```
const users = await User.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$and': [
            { '$gte': [{ '$toInt': '$date' }, 1 ] },
            { '$lte': [{ '$toInt': '$date' }, 11 ] }
        ]
    }   
})
```

---

The following query derivation returns the desired results with the existing conditions:

```
const toIntExpression = { '$toInt': '$date' }
const query = { 
    '$expr': {
        '$and': []
    } 
}

if (req.query.from) {
    const from = parseInt(req.query.from, 10)
    query['$expr']['$and'].push({
        '$gte': [toIntExpression, from]
    })
}

if (req.query.to) {
    const to = parseInt(req.query.to, 10)
    query['$expr']['$and'].push({
        '$lte': [toIntExpression, to]
    })
}

const users = await User.find(query)
```